# Avoid recursive rendering with promises?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Heres my simplified React component:

```
import React from "react"
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux"
import { useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom"
import gameService from "../services/game"
import {setGame} from "../reducers/game" //action creator

const Game = () => {
    const game = useSelector(state => state.game)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const match = useRouteMatch('/games/:id')
    gameService.oneGame(match.params.id).then(g => dispatch(setGame(g)))

    const gameInfo = (game) => {
        ...some proceessing
        return(JSX containig info about the game)
    }

    return(
        game ? <div>
            <h2>{game.name}</h2>
            {gameInfo(game)}
         </div> :
         loading
    )
} 

export default Game
```

Component is called from App.js:

```
    <Route path="/games/:id">
        <Game />
    </Route>
```

Everything works but the site renders infinitely. Does the promise resolve after the component has rendered and this renders the component again, or what is happenig here? And what is the easiest fix?

Comment: [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)?

Answer (score 3):

I think you may want to put the call to `gameService` in a `useEffect` hook so that it is only called when `match.params.id` and `dispatch` change rather than every time the component is re-rendered.

Try amending it to be:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux"
import { useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom"
import gameService from "../services/game"
import {setGame} from "../reducers/game" //action creator

const Game = () => {
    const game = useSelector(state => state.game)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const match = useRouteMatch('/games/:id')
    useEffect(() => {
         gameService.oneGame(match.params.id).then(g => dispatch(setGame(g)))
    }, [match.params.id, dispatch]);

    const gameInfo = (game) => {
        ...some proceessing
        return(JSX containig info about the game)
    }

    return(
        game ? <div>
            <h2>{game.name}</h2>
            {gameInfo(game)}
         </div> :
         loading
    )
} 

export default Game
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, solved my problem. I previously tried your approach, but my useEffect second argument was [match, dispatch] instead of [match.params.id, dispatch]. This still caused endless rendering. Can you explain why this happens?

Comment: I'd guess that the `match` value is causing the rerender since it is an object and useEffect will check to see if the `match` value is the same object as the previous `match` value. If that object is being re-instantiated on each render then useEffect will continue firing. useEffect uses referential equality not deep comparison equality